# Prevent anonymous class from referencing outer members in Java

Tags: java

In Java, is there a way to explicitly prevent an anonymous class to reference the outer class or method's members/local variables?

Comment: Don't make it an anonymous class?

Comment: Why is this a thing you want?

Comment: Don't believe so, because you can always do this from the inner class: `Class.this.member`

Comment: An anonymous class _always_ has a reference to the enclosing outer class.  To avoid that you'll have to create it in a static method or create a named static inner class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/758570/is-it-possible-to-make-anonymous-inner-classes-in-java-static

Comment: It sounds just like asking : how do I prevent instance method to access instance fields...

Comment: You could create an entirely class that `extends`/`implements` the anonymous class's type. If the fields in the other class were `private`, they wouldn't be referenceable from outside that class. Hope that made sense.

Comment: sigh, why is this being downvoted/closed? it's a legitimate, objective, specific, programming question that has potential for others as well as the OP.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't. You always define anonymous classes inside other classes, e.g.

```
class A {

    private String aMember;

    public void test() {
        B b = new B() {

            @Override
            public void b() {
                ...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

You can always use `OuterClassName.this.something` to access the outer class:

```
@Override
public void b() {
    A.this.aMember = "Hello";
}
```

Why do you want to restrict access to the outer class? Once we know that, we could better understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: So with Java 8, I want to pass lambda like Function<INPUT, OUTPUT> to some places, and I want the lambda to be exactly a function of input to output, not able to use something else outside the lambda.

Comment: @Pinch: Why do you want that? Are you aiming to enforce "pure" functions? You're onto a loser, because I can still `new Random().nextInt()` or `MySingletonClass.getSomethingElse()`

Comment: @Pinch A lambda is not an anonymous class. There is no reference to an enclosing instance. They only hold onto references explicitly used in the body.

Comment: @PaulBoddington: is that behavior of lambda not referencing the outer class instance documented?

Comment: @Pinch Read this: http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~briangoetz/lambda/lambda-state-final.html The relevant bit is 7: Variable Capture, but the whole thing is worth reading.